# Specificity / inheritance of color from asterisk / body?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I am little confused with the following css

```
* {
    color: yellow;
}
body {
    color: black;
}
```

and HTML

```
    <div>
        <p> Test text... </p>

    </div>
```

any "p" under the body, would get a color of yellow - but why ? The asterisk has not got a weight.

and color is inherited so why doesn't the color of my "p" takes its color from the body ?

Instead it uses the color from the asterisk.

I mean, if a "body" and "p" (and anything in the line of inheritance) doesn't have a color then it should use the asterisk.

Can anyone help ? why the above is the way it is.

The chunk of html above gets a color of yellow but why does it not have black (which comes from the body) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean, if a "body" and "p" (and anything in the line of inheritance) doesn't have a background-color then it should use the asterisk.

The asterisk is a part of a selector that means "any element", not a special rule that means the properties within are applied as defaults when they have no inherited or specified value.

For example, another way to match `body` (but also `head`) would be:

```
html > * {
    …
}
```

because `body` is *an element* (`*`) that is a child of (`>`) an element named “html” (`html`).

So your `body` rule applies a background color to the body, but your `*` rule applies a background color to the `p`.

(Background color is also not an inherited property, but it doesn’t matter in this case. `color` would behave the same.)

Comment: I am not sure I am still understanding. So under normal circumstances, my P would inherit from body but because there is a asterisk it does not ?

So P would ignore the inheritance of color from body and apply the asterisk instead ?

Comment: @Martin Not because there’s an asterisk specifically, but because there’s a rule that targets it and applies a value for `color`, yes. The **body element**: has a default `color: inherit`; the `* { color: yellow }` rule changes it to `color: yellow`, because body is matched by `*`; the `body { color: black }` rule changes it to `color: black`, because body is matched by `body` – this rule takes precedence because `body` has a higher specificity than `*`. The **p element**: has a default `color: inherit`; the `* { color: yellow }` rule changes it to `color: yellow`, because p is matched by `*`.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand.